# Review Queue - Scope for a brief 'Stop the Clock' feature after Mod comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often when I look at the review queues I see that there are posts which have had constructive comments left for the OP, which if acted on would avoid the need for the post to be deleted. The problem is that the comment has often only been left a few minutes before and it seems harsh to continue casting VTC when an OP who may be new to the whole set-up has yet to have chance to respond.

I imagine that the reason I only see such comments when they are typically less than an hour old is that there isn't often a significant review queue at all when I am on the site, so I assume that generally things are cleared quickly once they make it to the queue.

But this issue of people continuing to VTC when the OP has very probably not had chance yet to see the constructive comment, often from a Mod, let alone act on it always makes me uncomfortable.

Is there any way that for Moderator comments at least, we could built in some sort of 'stop the clock' suspension from the review queue for a few hours to give the OP a fighting chance and be less discouraging/more welcoming?

I understand that the OP can edit a deleted answer and try to get it reopened, but I wonder how often that happens with newer users. Are they finding their questions whisked through the review queues and struck off and then thinking, 'well that was a bust' and wandering off to Quora?

Comment: I'm unsure of how viable this is technically, but I can confirm that the process of deletion/undeletion needs additional clarification/publicity. I have been a user of various stackexchange sites for over 3 years and only last month did I figure out that things could get undeleted, and only because I happened to be in a chatroom where this fact came up.

Comment: Are you talking about votes to close or votes to delete? These are different mechanisms.

Comment: @sphennings Vote to Close i suppose, tbh I'm slightly foggy about when closed questions do or don't get deleted.

Comment: With the exception of triggering auto deletion. Closing and deleting questions are unrelated. You can read more about the specifics of deletion and what triggers auto deletion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). Right now it's pretty unclear which you are talking about. And whether you're talking about questions or answers. Could you [edit] this to make it clearer?

Comment: Why do you think closing needs to wait until after the OP gets the message? Reopening is triggered by an edit to the question.

Comment: I've undeleted this because I think it asks an important question that needs to be talked about here. I've tried to address that in my answer.

Comment: @Catja cheers. I ended up confused as to whether I had asked something that didn't make sense and was going to come back to it when I had more time in a few days to see what I could revise and improve.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Does my answer help at all? If I can add anything, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 9):

I think that this request makes sense if you assume that closing a question (or in this case, putting it "on hold") is an end game that can't be recovered from but when you really understand the purpose of being put on hold, this request is actually already implemented by that status.

The main goal of putting a question on hold is to give the user the chance to *fix* the question while preventing answers from being posted. Particularly on a site like Interpersonal Skills, where everyone has an opinion, **preventing answers to questions that still need work should be one of our number one goals**.

Here's the description from the [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) about what being "on hold" means:

> If a question has been closed (except as a duplicate), then for the first 5 days, it is marked as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During this period, if the question is edited, it will be added to the reopen queue. Other than this, there is no functional difference between “on hold” and “closed”.

I know that there's a lot of bad feelings about closing questions being "mean" or poorly received from users, particularly those who are unfamiliar with the system and I think that needs to be addressed somehow, on a network-wide level because it's absolutely not just here that it's a concern.

For the time being, though, the best advice I can give is to emphasize to users that, while their question is *currently* not a good fit for the site, it can be improved and we will help them with that, even if the question is put on hold and, if improved, we will reopen the question so that it may be answered.

This puts the onus in their court, though. If they want a great answer, they'll need to write a great question and improve it and that improves the site. If they don't want to do that, to put in the effort, then they're free to go elsewhere. We can only do so much to help.